# How to get the value of a selected radio input element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, input

```
  <input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="HTML">HTML</input>
  <input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="C++">C++ </input>
  <input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="JavaScript">JavaScript </input>
  <input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="Python">Python</input>
  <button type="submit" class="submit">check</button>
```

**Here is my html code**
I'm trying to get the value of the selected radio element after the click of the button element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
const btnSubmit = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]');

btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let checkedInputValue = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="programming"]:checked').value;
    console.log(checkedInputValue);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value with JavaScript with :

```
document.querySelector('input[name="programming"]:checked').value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="HTML">HTML</input>
<input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="C++">C++ </input>
<input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="JavaScript">JavaScript </input>
<input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="Python">Python</input>
<button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="submit">check</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById('submitBtn').onclick = function(){
       let val = document.querySelector('input[name="programming"]:checked').value; 
       console.log('Choosen: ', val)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first add the click listener to button, then check inside the click event the value of `input[name="programming"]:checked`.
See my code for better understanding.

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".submit");

button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
 alert(document.querySelector('input[name="programming"]:checked').value);
});
```

```html
 <input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="HTML">HTML</input>
  <input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="C++">C++ </input>
  <input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="JavaScript">JavaScript </input>
  <input type="radio" name="programming" id="" value="Python">Python</input>
  <button type="submit" class="submit">check</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Selecting all the input with name of programming
const selectedRadio = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='programming']");

// selecting the btn to which we will add the event listener
const btn = document.querySelector(".submit");

//  adding a click event to the selected button
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    
    // looping through each btn and logging the value unto the console if it is checked
    selectedRadio.forEach((element => {
        if(element.checked) {
            console.log(element.value);
        };
    }));
});
```